# Finding value of $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5})$ in equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Consider the system of equations $$x_{1}+x^2_{2}+x^3_{3}+x^4_{4}+x^5_{5} =5$$
>
> and $$x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}+4x_{4}+5x_{5}=15$$
>
> where $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5}$ are positive real numbers, Then number of $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5})$ is

My Try: From inspection $x_{1}=x_{2}=x_{3}=x_{4}=x_{5}=1$

could some help me how to prove that other solution does not exists, thanks

Comment: There are 5 unknowns and 2 equations, it is very unlikely that no other solution exists.

Comment: @Durgesh: These questions, along with the other ones you have posted, these seems like competition questions. Maybe Olympiad elimination round?

Comment: Why has this been declared off-topic? Which topic is it off of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$15=x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}+4x_{4}+5x_{5}\leq x_1+1+x_2^2+2+x_3^3+3+x_4^4+4+x_5^5,$$
which gives
$$x_1+x_2^2+x_3^3+x_4^4+x_5^5\geq5.$$
The equality occurs for $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=1$ only, which gives an unique solution.

Comment: I’m having trouble following the AM-GM logic. For example, why is $5x^5\leq4+x^5$? Would it not be $5x^5=\sqrt{5^2x^{10}}\leq \frac{25+x^{10}}{2}$? Maybe I’m reading it wrong. Would you please add a step or so in the answer to clarify?

Comment: @Mathemagical It's $5x\leq4+x^5$ fot positive $x$. $4+x_5^5=1+1+1+1+x_5^5\geq5\sqrt[5]{1^4x_5^5}=5x_5.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Oh, got it. That’s clever! +1

Comment: But wait...this only shows that the function $x_1+x_2^2+x^3^3+x_4^4+x_5^5$ attains it’s minimum at the point $(1,1,1,1,1)$. But not that the minimum is achieved only at this point (could be w few other points where the function is 5.  The other two answers here, from @achillehui and me, do actually show that the minimum is achieved at a unique point.  I think you can modify your answer to make it so too (by adding the strict convexity argument I have made, for example).

Comment: @Mathemagical But for positive $x_3$ we have $x_3^3+3=3x_3$ for $x_3=1$ only. Thus, the equality occurs for $x_i=1$ only.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Okay. But in principle, there could still be some other combination of the other 4 coordinates where the minimum is achieved. In any case, I think adding the arguments explicitly in the answer to nail the uniqueness will only improve the answer (as that is the main point of the question).

Comment: I think you are right. We need to  say about this point.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg By the way, any idea why this question was put on hold as off-topic? Seems a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @Mathemagical You can try to open this topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don’t have sufficient rep points for that yet.

Answer (score 5):

We will use the strict version of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality).

> For every integer $r \ge 0$ and real number $\epsilon \ge -1$, we have
>   $$(1+\epsilon)^r \ge 1 + r\epsilon$$
>   and the inequality is strict when $r \ge 2$ and $\epsilon \ne 0$.

For $i = 1,\ldots, 5$, rewrite $x_k$ as $1 + \epsilon_k$. 
In terms of $\epsilon_k$, the second conditions becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 kx_k = 15\iff \sum_{k=1}^5 k(1+\epsilon_k) = 15 \iff \sum_{k=1}^5 k\epsilon_k = 0\tag{*1}$$

For the first condition, we have

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k^k = 5
& \iff \sum_{k=1}^5 ((1+\epsilon_k)^k - 1 ) = 0\\
& \implies \sum_{k=1}^5 ((1+\epsilon_k)^k - (1+k\epsilon_k)) = 0\\
&\iff \sum_{k=2}^5 ((1+\epsilon_k)^k - (1+k\epsilon_k)) = 0
\end{align}
$$

Notice all $x_k > 0$, we have all $\epsilon_k > -1$. We can apply the strict version of Bernoulli's inequality and conclude
$\epsilon_2 = \epsilon_3 = \epsilon_4 = \epsilon_5 = 0$.
Together with $(*1)$, we find $\epsilon_1 = 0$ too.
As a result, the only possible solution has all $\epsilon_k = 0$ which is equivalent to all $x_k = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functions $f,g:\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R$ defined by 
$$x_1=f(x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=5-x_2^2-x_3^3-x_4^4-x_5^5$$and 
$$x_1= g(x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=15-2x_2-3x_3-4x_4+5x_5$$

As you have noted, at the point $y=(1,1,1,1)$, $$x_1=f(y)=g(y)=1$$
But note also that $$\nabla f(y)=\nabla g(y)=(-2,-3,-4,-5)$$ that is, they share a tangent plane at $y$. Since $g$ is already a linear function over $\mathbb{R}^4$ plus a constant, it ***is*** the tangent plane to the function $f$ at $y$.

Since $f$ is readily seen to be strictly concave (it’s a sum of strictly concave functions in each dimension) on the domain in question, it must lie below its tangent plane $x_1=g$, meeting only at the point $y$.